# query syntax for aggregates not working as advertised

Tags: ponyorm

I'm trying to formulate a query that fetches two aggregate (avg) columns. There is no group by, I want the aggregates calculated across the entire result set.

I want to calculate the avg of a couple of attributes across the latest result for each user meeting certain criteria.

The following raw sql works fine:

```
SELECT AVG(r.points), AVG(r.maxforanswered)
FROM "result" r,
     "user" u
WHERE
        u.birth_date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - ($highage * 365) 
                                      AND CURRENT_DATE - ($lowage * 365)
        AND u.gender = $gender
        AND r.user = u.id
        AND r.time_generated = (SELECT MAX(r2.time_generated) 
                                FROM "result" r2 
                                WHERE r2.user = u.id)
```

I have tried a number of formulations. As I read the documentation this should work:

```
select((avg(r.points), avg(r.maxforanswered))
            for r in Result
            for u in User
            if r.user == u
               and u.gender == gender
               and between(u.birth_date, dminus, dplus)
               and r.time_generated == 
                max(r2.time_generated for r2 in Result if r2.user == u))
```

Documentation says that aggregate columns will not be included in GROUP BY. But I get an error that indicates this isn't right:

> pony.orm.dbapiprovider.ProgrammingError: aggregate functions are not
>   allowed in GROUP BY LINE 11: GROUP BY AVG("r"."points"),
>   AVG("r"."maxforanswered")

I'd like to know what the pony syntax would be (if there is one) to directly implement what is easy to do in SQL.

Comment: I guess it should be an issue not SO question.